# Adding Dictionary A values to Dictionary B at specifc points?

Tags: swift

Iv been trying to pick my way to solving this problem but havnt had any luck.

Here is the problem im trying to solve.

**Problem**

I have two dictionaries. `Dictionary A` is a `Array of Dictionaries` and `Dictionary B` is also a `Array of Dictionaries`. (See example below).

When the app lauches it grabs `Dictionary A` from a Firebase DB and stores it in `var dict`. Then it grabs `Dictionary B` from a Firebase DB located under the specific user's data.

I need to put the values from `Dictionary B` into specific spots in `Dictionary A`.

`Dictionary A` contains items in the game you can unlock with points. `Dictionary B` contains all the guns a specific user has unlocked.

Dictionary A (example)

```
let items : [[String:String]] = [

    [
        "type" : "Star 1",
        "model" : "Jungle Spray",
        "available" : "no",
        "rarity" : "normal",
        "totalOwned" : "1",
        "price" : "9,999"
    ],
    [
        "type" : "Star 1",
        "model" : "Predator",
        "available" : "no",
        "rarity" : "normal",
        "totalOwned" : "1",
        "price" : "10,500"
    ],
    [
        "type" : "Star 1",
        "model" : "Safari Mesh",
        "available" : "no",
        "rarity" : "normal",
        "totalOwned" : "1",
        "price" : "12,950"
    ],
```

Dictionary B (example)

```
  let userUnlocked : [[String: String]] = [


       [
            "type" : "Star 1",
            "model" : "Predator",
            "available" : "yes",
            "rarity" : "normal",
            "totalOwned" : "1",
            "price" : "9,999"
        ]

]
```

As you can see the only thing changed is the value `available` is set to `yes`. Which means this specific user has unlocked this gun. So I would need to overwrite this array in `Dictionary A` to show that yes the user has unlocked it.

Answer (score 1):

Terminology may be a little confusing.  Dictionaries do not have a specific order.  Arrays do.  You can insert into the items array using the Array method insert(_:atIndex:).

Also note, that if the array's are declared as let, you wont be able to add to it (need to change it to var).

```
userUnlocked.insert(items[0], atIndex: 1)
```

**TIP:**
You might also consider using a single array and adding a field for 'unlocked'.  Then you can easily grab the guns you want with:

```
items.map() { $0.unlocked == true }  //just an example, and wont work like this on your current dictionaries.
```

which will return an array of only unlocked guns.  `Map`, `Filter`, and `Reduce` are great higher order functions in Swift!

Comment: Dictionary A is a basic dictionary in Firebase thats used to outline a specific data structure in a CollectionViewController on the App. Each cell in the CollectionViewController is a "gun". When the player goes to that CollectionViewController it will back the Dictionary A and also Dictionary B (which is all the guns that the current user unlocked) and update Dictionary A. Then It will use Dictionary A to create the `cells` (each gun is a cell). The arrays in the updated Dictionary A with the key:value `available = yes` will show images and `no` will show a locked image. This is why :)

Comment: If that makes sense. So you says Since Dictionary A is a Array of Dictionaries it will never be in the same order, even if i save the indexes?

Comment: The Array of dictionaries will maintain order, but items within the dictionary will not maintain order.  Since each dictionary is representing a unique item, a struct to represent those items might be a better way to go (gives you more flexibility).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are keeping track of the indices for the arrays of why you would want to modify items, but if what you want is access a value in one of the dictionaries in userUnlock and set a value in items to be equal to that. see below:

1) if you want to modify items, you have to change it to var instead of let which makes it a constant

2) let's say you want to set the value for the "available" key in the first dictionary in items to the value for the "available" key in the second dictionary in userUnlock

```
items[0]["available"]  = userUnlocked[1]["available"]
```

After this line of code:

```
var items : [[String:String]] = [

  [
    "type" : "Star 1",
    "model" : "Jungle Spray",
    "available" : "yes",
    "rarity" : "normal",
    "totalOwned" : "1",
    "price" : "9,999"
  ],
  [
    "type" : "Star 1",
    "model" : "Predator",
    "available" : "no",
    "rarity" : "normal",
    "totalOwned" : "1",
    "price" : "10,500"
  ],
  [
    "type" : "Star 1",
    "model" : "Safari Mesh",
    "available" : "no",
    "rarity" : "normal",
    "totalOwned" : "1",
    "price" : "12,950"
  ]
]
```

Note: Response to your comment

```
for i in 0...items.count-1
{
  if items[i]["model"] == "Predator"
  {
    items[i]["available"] = "yes"
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: What if i wanted to update a specific array in `Dictionary A`? I updated `Dictionary B` above with only one array inside. So I would want to update a `array` in `Dictionary A` that has the `model = Predator'.

Comment: I will modify the answer to show you what I would do at the end

Comment: Ah ok that is helping me get to the solution :). In the full game Dictionary A will have 100 - 200 "items". The average player will only have 20 - 25 of them unlocked in Dictionary B. How do i interate through all the array's in Dictionary B and copy the new data into the correct spots in Dictionary A? ( Correct spot meaning the array with the same "model")

Comment: 1. Find the `index` in `Dictionary A` that matches the current `index` that we are iterating through using your example above (for i in 0...userUnlocked.count-1). Since each index array has a unique `model` key thats how we should search I assume? So say we have to search `Dictionary A` for a `index` containing the key `model = Predator` or any other model the user unlocked.

Comment: 2. Then Copy the current Index dictionary (the one we are iterating through) to the correct `index` matching the model in `Dictionary B`

Comment: `for i in 0...udb.count-1 {
         
            let x = udb[i]["model"]
            for i in bdb.count-1 {
         
                if bdb[i]["model"] == x {
                    
                    bdb[i]["available"] == "yes"
         
                }
         
            }
         
         }
`

Comment: What is the -1 after `udb.count-1` for?

Comment: can you tell me what the `items.count-1` is for? the `-1`

Comment: sure, items.count gives you the size of items; if we use that as an index for it we will be out of bounds since we have to start at 0, so I removed 1 from it to remain within bounds